# Equal height columns with toast css framework

Tags: css, height, equals, toast-css

Is there any way to get equal height column with toast css without js? 
http://daneden.me/toast/

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eD4aY/1/

```
.grid {
margin-left: -3%;
max-width: 105%;
}

.unit {
background-color: #82A1FF;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
vertical-align: top;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: -.25em;
/* Clearfix */
overflow: hidden;
*overflow: visible;
}



.one-of-two { width: 47%; }
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you look at *any* equal height columns techniques?

Comment: Yes, i've tested many methods but i wasn't able to get it work with toast css.

Comment: You can use the: "min-height" property, but note that the height will be static...

Comment: Yes, but in my case min-height will not help me.